# Ruby Constructors and Exceptions

Tags: ruby, exception, constructor

New to Ruby, and I'm trying to figure out what idiom to use to restrict some integer values to the constructor of a class.

From what I've done so far, if I raise an exception in `initialize()`, the object is still created but will be in an invalid state (for example, some `nil` values in instance variables).  I can't quite see how I'm supposed to restrict the values without going into what looks unnecessarily big steps like restricting access to `new()`.

So my question is, by what mechanism can I restrict the range of values an object is instantiated with?

Comment: Yeah, I confused myself on this problem.  I was `rescue`ing the exception in the constructor, so it stands to reason that the instance would be created.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Huh, you are entirely correct that the object still lives even if `initialize` raises an exception. However, it will be quite hard for anyone to hang on to a reference unless you leak `self` out of `initialize` like the following code I just wrote does:

```
>> class X
>>   def initialize
>>     $me = self
>>     raise
>>   end
>>   def stillHere!
>>     puts "It lives!"
>>   end
>> end
=> nil
>> t = X.new
RuntimeError: 
    from (irb):14:in `initialize'
    from (irb):20:in `new'
    from (irb):20
>> t
=> nil
>> $me
=> #<X:0xb7ab0e70>
>> $me.stillHere!
It lives!
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about this statement:

> From what I've done so far, if I raise
>   an exception in initialize(), the
>   object is still created but will be in
>   an invalid state (for example, some
>   nil values in instance variables).

```
class Foo

  def initialize(num)
    raise ArgumentError.new("Not valid number") if num > 1000
    @num = num
  end 

end

f = Foo.new(4000) #=> n `initialize': not valid (RuntimeError)
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to have to review my code and see if maybe I'm mistaken.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Actually, the object *is* created, it's just that .new won't return the reference, so unless the object links to itself during `initialize` it will get gc'ed.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your question correctly, what you want is something like this:

```
class SerialNumber
  VALID_SERIAL_NUMBERS = (0..10,000,000,000)
  def initialize(n)
    raise ArgumentError.new("Serial numbers must be positive integers less than 10 Billion") unless VALID_SERIAL_NUMBERS.include?(n)
    @n = n
  end
end
```

Don't worry that SerialNumber.new creates an instance before that `initialize` method is called -- it'll get cleaned up if the error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [validatable module](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/02/ruby-validatable.html) seems like a really good fit in the context.

Here is an example for how to use it:

```
  class Person
    include Validatable
    validates_numericality_of :age
  end
```

For doing a numbers only in a particular range it would be:

```
  class Person
    include Validatable
    validates_numericality_of :age
    validates_true_for :age, :logic => lambda { (0..100).include?(age) }
  end
```

This of course will validate that age is within the range of 0 and 100.